# One hyper link below each legend of pi-chart

Tags: highcharts

```
legend: {
                enabled: true,
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                labelFormatter: function () {
                    return this.y + ' ' + this.name;
                }
```

Hi

I have a special requirement.
I need a one hyper link below each legend of pi-chart.

Under each legend one hyper link should appear.

At present I am managing it by updating labelFormatter as below.

```
return this.y + ' ' + this.name+ '<br /> <a href="google.com/">' + this.x + '…. </a>'
```

is there any better way of doing this?

http://www.highcharts.com/
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic

Answer (score 0):

That's the best way as @Sebastian Bochan said.
But if you want you can do something like this:

```
var urlData = ['Google','Bing','Yahoo','Other'];
```

And then (same for href):

```
return this.y + ' ' + this.name+ '<br /> <a href="google.com/">' + urlData[this.x] + '</a>'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uWAvP/3745/